# Showing custom object fields in page layout containing a lookup

Tags: custom-object, lookup

I have a custom object called "Branche" which contains a number and a description field. My Account page layout contains a lookup field to this custom object. Currently, it shows just the number. How can I make it show the description and the number at once (or any other field for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the field to "Branche" **Lookup Dialogs** in Search Layout and then you will see the field while searching for Branche records

When you add fields to lookup dailogs.

[image]

Then you will see something like this.

[image]